# Enable Drag&Drop in Overlayed Calendars | SP2010

Tags: 2010, list, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to find a way to enable users to use the standard Sharepoint Calendar Drag&Drop function for overlayed calendars as well.

For now, Users can only Drag&Drop events that are in the main calendar ; all events in the overlayed calendars must be clicked into, and the date changed manually.

In this particular case, the Overlayed Calendars are just the same calendar, but with different views specified.

I haven't found an option for this in the site admin controls.

Any ideas ?

thank you for your help !